# Design tool or designing tool

Tags: orthography

Which is the correct form?

- Collaborative Unified Modelling Language **design** tool for software development teams
- Collaborative Unified Modelling Language **designing** tool for software development teams

Comment: It's *design*, but god knows why. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say **design tool**, although (like Gleno's comment) I have a difficult time explaining why. Since I can't really explain why, I figured I'd show some evidence of use.

[image]

**Design tool** is the clear winner here.

EDIT: Image generated using [Google Ngram Viewer](http://books.google.com/ngrams).

Comment: May I ask you where you generated that diagram?

Comment: It's from Google Ngram Viewer, lots of fun! http://books.google.com/ngrams

Comment: Oops, forgot to mention that. Link added.